# Permission denied error in pip installing pyopenssl

Tags: python, pip, python-cffi, pycparser

As I'm trying to force reinstall `pyopenssl`, I'm running into the following error when it tries to install `pycparser`.  I am doing this on Windows 7 64-bit with Python 2.7 using the following command:

```
pip install pyopenssl --ignore-installed
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\req\req_set.py", line 742, in install
        **kwargs
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\req\req_install.py", line 831, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
        isolated=self.isolated,
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\wheel.py", line 324, in clobber
        shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4\\Lib\\site-packages\\_cffi_backend.pyd'
```

Here is what I have noticed:

- It only happens with `_cffi_backend.pyd` - other packages install and
  uninstall fine.
- I can `pip uninstall cffi` and re-install it alright, but whenever it
  is present, the `_cffi_backend.pyd` permission error presents.  This means that any installations calling `cffi` (for example `pyopenssl`) will fail.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling `cffi`: no effect
2. Successfully used icalcs to set `_cffi_backend.pyd` to full access, everyone: no effect
3. Calling `pip` with `python -m pip install pyopenssl --ignore-installed`: no effect
4. Closed all applications and examined running processes before
   installing: no effect
5. Reboot.  Voodoo for the most part, but just to be thorough: no effect

Comment: Try using a command prompt with elevated privileges

Comment: That is not an option for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: There a possibility that `_cffi_backend.pyd` is running as a background process, hence windows is preventing reinstallation. However, uninstall is probably written to shut down the background process which allows the installer to remove the file.

Comment: Maybe ``cffi`` is used by the pip process itself (importing stuff that ends up importing cffi)?  Try ``python -i -m pip install ...`` and when you get the crash, inspect ``"_cffi_backend" in sys.modules``.

Comment: Thanks Armin, I'm not familiar with that level of error research, could you help me with the syntax that you would use after `import sys` from the python prompt (following the crash)?